# How to bootstrap Aurelia in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, aurelia

I want to use Aurelia in a Laravel 5 application, but I'm having difficulties with bootstrapping Aurelia.

I installed Aurelia in the `public/test` folder of Laravel. Then, renamed the default `index.html` that comes with the Aurelia skeleton app to `index.php`. The content in there is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Aurelia</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= URL::asset('test/styles/styles.css'); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

  <body aurelia-app>
    <script src="<?= URL::asset('test/jspm_packages/system.js'); ?>"></script>
    <script src="<?= URL::asset('test/config.js'); ?>"></script>
    <script>
      SystemJS.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But the bootstrapping is not working because it's trying to load Aurelia from the following location:

```
http://localhost/cms/public/index.php/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-bootstrapper@1.0.0-beta.1.1.2.js
```

Note that `index.php` is in the URL. It is also missing the sub folder `test` in the url this way. This basically prevents it from loading the right file.

How can I solve this issue in Laravel?

Comment: Why don't you just use plain html/js for the frontend and use laravel for the backend? You don't need server to render static paths of your app

Answer (score 0):

Aurelia and Laravel aren't meant to mix in that way...You could create an api with Laravel (or even better use [lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/) ), and build the front end seperately calling your api through Aurelia.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using laravel for API backend and Aurelia for UI, a very simple approach is to serve both independently using your web server.

Here is a working configuration that we are using for a similar setup on centos 7 and nginx. I am sure similar setup can work on ubuntu as well.

Laravel app resides in

```
/user/share/nginx/html/laravel-app/
```

and the aurelia app reside in

```
/user/share/nginx/html/aurelia-app/
```

and this is the nginx conf file we use to server the app

```
file# /etc/nginx/conf.d/my-app.conf
server {
    listen     80;
    server_name  my-app.com www.my-app.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/myapp-access.log  main;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/myapp-error.log error;

    root  /usr/share/nginx/html/laravel-app/public;


    charset utf-8;

    location / {
          alias /usr/share/nginx/html/aurelia-app/dist/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }

    location /api/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$is_args?$args;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   localhost:9000;
        fastcgi_buffering off;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```